# GDI Objects or USER Objects?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2009, popupmenu

I have an application that allows a user to open multiple windows/modules.  Each module has it's own popup menu, some of these are create at runtime when a form is created, some design time and I have a lot of them in each module, some are used when I right click a form, some are used in toolbutton.

The problem I have is that I have a lot of windows opened, when I right click to access the popup menu, the generated menu goes haywire, I mean, it's not showing the correct labels.  Sometimes it'll show all "Save as.." or any other label I need to display.  I guess the easiest way to explain this is by showing you a screenshot of the menu

[image: normal menu]

[image: incorrect menu]

[image: incorrect menu again]

Is this a GDI/User Objects problem?  If so, how do I resolve this?  I tried increasing my GDI and Uses object limits as a test but still getting this problem.  The problem will be resolve if I close one or two windows; however, I cannot ask my users to limit the number of windows opened in the application.  A check with windows task manager shows that my application is using 4,312 User Objects and 5,570 GDI objects with 437 Handles at the time this problem is occuring.

Comment: Make sure you are not leaking any of those many GDI objects

Comment: I doubt its a gdi/user objects issue. Looks more like a coding issue. Something is not being handled properly. Is you run out of GDI/User objects you will stop getting any windows at all.